# Tuple consumes first singleton dimension of NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy

Given a NumPy array:

```
    array = np.random.randn(1,1,2)
    print(array.shape)
    # (1, 1, 2)
```

calling tuple() on it eats the first dimension:

```
    tupled_array = tuple(array)
    print(tupled_array[0].shape)
    # (1, 2) <- why?
```

I am curious about why?

If we wrap the NumPy array with a list:

```
    tupled_list_array = tuple([array])
    print(tupled_list_array[0].shape)
    # (1, 1, 2)
```

Comment: `np.ndarray` implements `__iter__` which is what `tuple` uses to loop over the items and put them inside a tuple. `__iter__` returns a bunch of `np.ndarray`s (or rather, slices, I would presume).

Comment: Both `tuple(array)` and `list(array)` iterate on the first dimension of the array (which in this case happens to be size 1 - but that's not significant).  A list comprehension does as well `[a for a in array]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tuple() extracts elements based on the first dimension. np.random.randn(1,1,2) is a 1x1x2 matrix. tuple() turns it into the following tuple: (1x2 matrix, )

On the other hand, if you use np.random.randn(2,1,1), tuple() turns it into: (1x1 matrix, 1x1 matrix)